# how can I make a vertical and reverse decision tree in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

I am trying to make a vertical "reverse" decision tree inspired on [this](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/system-combination/).

This is my trial:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows}
\begin{document}
% Define block styles used later
\tikzstyle{sensor}=[draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, 
    text centered, minimum height=2.5em,drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{wa} = [sensor, text width=6em, fill=red!20, 
    minimum height=3em, rounded corners, drop shadow]
% Define distances for bordering
\def\blockdist{2.3}
\def\edgedist{2.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (wa) [wa]  {NB Best};
    \path (wa.west)+(-3.2,1.5) node (asr1) [sensor] {$NB_1$};
    \path (wa.west)+(-3.2,0.5) node (asr2)[sensor] {$NB_2$};
    \path (wa.west)+(-3.2,-0.5) node (asr3)[sensor] {$NB_3$}; 
    \path (wa.west)+(-3.2,-1.5) node (asr4)[sensor] {$NB_4$};    
   
    \path (wa.east)+(\blockdist,0) node (vote) [sensor] {NB filtered};

    \path [draw, ->] (asr1.east) -- node [above] {} 
        (wa.155) ;
    \path [draw, ->] (asr2.east) -- node [above] {} 
        (wa.170);
    \path [draw, ->] (asr3.east) -- node [above] {} 
        (wa.190);
    \path [draw, ->] (asr4.east) -- node [above] {} 
        (wa.205);
    \path [draw, ->] (wa.east) -- node [above] {} 
        (vote.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

When I try to use the same structure below this first tree, they overlap each other. And I don't know to fix it, and move on to the desired diagram:

[image]

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the use of a `scope` and `yshift`. The idea is to change the minimum for each block, which for me is the text of the nodes, not even their names. Then shift it in height. I have not deleted anything, but commented what is not neccesary so you have a reference, as I did not change your code. I added the "Best model" node.

The image:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
% Define block styles used later
\tikzstyle{sensor}=[draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, 
    text centered, minimum height=2.5em,drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{wa} = [sensor, text width=6em, fill=red!20, 
    minimum height=3em, rounded corners, drop shadow]
% Define distances for bordering
\def\blockdist{2.3}
\def\edgedist{2.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node (best) [wa, align = center] at (4,0) {BEST \\ MODEL};
    
    \begin{scope}[yshift = 3cm]
        \node (wa) [wa]  {P};
        \draw[-latex] (wa.east) -- (best);
        %\path (wa.west)+(-3.2,1.5) node (asr1) [sensor] {$NB_1$};
        \path (wa.west)+(-3.2,0.5) node (asr2)[sensor] {$P$};
        %\path (wa.west)+(-3.2,-0.5) node (asr3)[sensor] {$NB_3$}; 
        %\path (wa.west)+(-3.2,-1.5) node (asr4)[sensor] {$NB_4$};    
        
        %\path (wa.east)+(\blockdist,0) node (vote) [sensor] {NB filtered};
        
        %\path [draw, ->] (asr1.east) -- node [above] {} 
        %(wa.155) ;
        \path [draw, ->] (asr2.east) -- node [above] {} 
        (wa.170);
        %\path [draw, ->] (asr3.east) -- node [above] {} 
        %(wa.190);
        %\path [draw, ->] (asr4.east) -- node [above] {} 
        %(wa.205);
        %\path [draw, ->] (wa.east) -- node [above] {} 
        %(vote.west)
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[yshift = 0cm]
       \node (wa) [wa]  {NB Best};
       \draw[-latex] (wa.east) -- (best);
        \path (wa.west)+(-3.2,1.5) node (asr1) [sensor] {$NB_1$};
        \path (wa.west)+(-3.2,0.5) node (asr2)[sensor] {$NB_2$};
        \path (wa.west)+(-3.2,-0.5) node (asr3)[sensor] {$NB_3$}; 
        \path (wa.west)+(-3.2,-1.5) node (asr4)[sensor] {$NB_4$};    
        
        %\path (wa.east)+(\blockdist,0) node (vote) [sensor] {NB filtered};
        
        \path [draw, ->] (asr1.east) -- node [above] {} 
        (wa.155) ;
        \path [draw, ->] (asr2.east) -- node [above] {} 
        (wa.170);
        \path [draw, ->] (asr3.east) -- node [above] {} 
        (wa.190);
        \path [draw, ->] (asr4.east) -- node [above] {} 
        (wa.205);
        %\path [draw, ->] (wa.east) -- node [above] {} 
        %(vote.west);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[yshift = -5cm]
        \node (wa) [wa]  {CMP Best};
        \draw[-latex] (wa.east) -- (best);
        \path (wa.west)+(-3.2,1.5) node (asr1) [sensor] {$CMP_1$};
        \path (wa.west)+(-3.2,0.5) node (asr2)[sensor] {$CMP_2$};
        \path (wa.west)+(-3.2,-0.5) node (asr3)[sensor] {$CMP_3$}; 
        \path (wa.west)+(-3.2,-1.5) node (asr4)[sensor] {$CMP_4$};    
        
        %\path (wa.east)+(\blockdist,0) node (vote) [sensor] {CMP filtered};
        
        \path [draw, ->] (asr1.east) -- node [above] {} 
        (wa.155) ;
        \path [draw, ->] (asr2.east) -- node [above] {} 
        (wa.170);
        \path [draw, ->] (asr3.east) -- node [above] {} 
        (wa.190);
        \path [draw, ->] (asr4.east) -- node [above] {} 
        (wa.205);
        %\path [draw, ->] (wa.east) -- node [above] {} 
        %(vote.west);
    \end{scope}
    
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror,raise=4ex}]
    (wa.south) --++(4,0) node[midway,yshift=-5em, align = center]{Linear \\ Prediction \\  Filter};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry to bother. Is there a way to include a legend in on it? I tried with `\matrix [draw,above right] at (current bounding box.north east) {
  \node [label=1 Full model] {}; \\
  \node [label=2 Fixed variance] {}; \\
  \node [label=3 Comum variance] {}; \\
  \node [label=4 Fixed dispersion] {}; \\
};`, but I obtained a not beautiful legend. I just want to point the meaning of 1, 2, 3 and 4. It could be located in another position too

Comment: Hmm I am quite bad with these kind of labes and usually take a cavernman approach to them. Mostly, a multiline node (hehe). I did not test it, but probably something like this: `\node[align=left, anchor=south] (textNode) at (best.north) {1 - Full model // 2 - Fixed variance // 3 - Comum variance // 4 - Fixed dispersion};`. This allows you to do some easy formatting on the node. Let me know if it works and you like it!

Comment: Thank you Jes!! It work for me! I had to change // to \\ and (best.north) to (4,2) to the legend be placed in a further top right position

Comment: Oops sorry, I wrote this from my phone so I couldn't check it haha. Glad to be of help!

Comment: I imagined that hehe thank you for quick reply

Answer (score 2):

Similar solution to Jes one, but with `forest`

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shadows, decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}  
\begin{forest}
    for tree={grow=west, draw, 
         drop shadow, text centered,
        edge=Stealth-, child anchor=east, l sep=1cm,
        },
    where level=2{fill=blue!30, sharp corners, text width=5em, minimum height=2.5em, math content}%
    {text width=6em, minimum height=3em, rounded corners, fill=red!30,}
[BEST\\ MODEL, align=center, name=root
    [P
        [P]]
    [NB Best 
        [NB_1]
        [NB_2]
        [NB_3]
        [NB_4]]
    [CMP Best, name=CMP
        [CMP_1]
        [CMP_2]
        [CMP_3]
        [CMP_4]]]
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror,raise=4ex}]
    (CMP.south) --(CMP.south-|root) node[midway,yshift=-5em, align = center]{Linear \\ Prediction \\  Filter};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ooh clever! I am currently trying to learn foests and mindmaps so seeing these kind of possibikitirs are very helpful!

Comment: Sorry to bother. Is there a way to include a legend in on it? I tried with `\matrix [draw,above right] at (current bounding box.north east) {
  \node [label=1 Full model] {}; \\
  \node [label=2 Fixed variance] {}; \\
  \node [label=3 Comum variance] {}; \\
  \node [label=4 Fixed dispersion] {}; \\
};`, but I obtained a not beautiful legend. I just want to point the meaning of 1, 2, 3 and 4. It could be located in another position too

Comment: @GuilhermeParreira the solution provided by Jes can be also applied here. If you want a particular `node` as reference, add the name to it.

Comment: Thank you Ignasi!!